# Powershell get page number containing the comment

Tags: powershell, comments

How do I get page number of a comment in `WordDocument`?

```
$doc.Comments| ForEach-Object{
   Write-Host $_.Author"," $_.Date"," $_.Range.Text `r`n 
   # comment page number?
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Word doesn't store page numbers for any of its objects as you can see inside the docx xml yourself, but it's possible to get it from the comment's scope using [wdActiveEndPageNumber](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdinformation(v=office.15).aspx) information:

```
$doc.Comments | %{
    $pageNo = $_.Scope.Information(3) # wdActiveEndPageNumber
    $_.Author, $_.Date, $_.Range.Text, $pageNo -join ', '
}
```

P.S. I think it's probable Word doesn't recalculate the actual page number but uses the internal [LastRenderedPageBreak](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.lastrenderedpagebreak(v=office.15).aspx) element (`<w:lastRenderedPageBreak/>` in XML file) that theoretically could be inaccurate in some cases (e.g. a font is missing on your PC and a substitute is used with different character width/height causing reflow of the pages).

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. It was helpful.